# Can't install qt with brew for macOS 10.12 after meeting all prerequisites

Tags: qt, gnuplot, homebrew, macos-sierra

Trying to install qt in macOS Sierra (10.12.6) using brew. I run $ brew info qt and get the following:

```
$ brew info qt
qt: stable 5.15.0, HEAD [keg-only]
Cross-platform application and UI framework
https://www.qt.io/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/qt.rb

==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✔
Required: macOS >= 10.12 ✔
```

With this I assume I have everything required to install it. However, if I run $ brew install qt, this appears:

```
1 error generated.

make: *** [qcore_mac.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
```

What is wrong then?

Context:

I am working with terminal and have little coding background. I'm trying to install gnuplot and I'm only missing qt and pango dependencies.

Comment: Qt 5.15 supports only macOS 10.13 and newer, you must use Qt <= 5.12. see https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/macos.html

Comment: Yes, just found that same page but it's weird since the brew info says macOS >= 10.12 is fine. Is there a way to install Qt <= 5.12 from brew? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Actually @FrankOsterfeld, I've been reading and apparently there isn't a direct way to do it from brew. Do you know how else it can be done? Thanks

Edit: I've been trying to follow this :
https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code
but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I'd try first with the Qt online installer (requires to create an account with Qt but otherwise free) or the dmg here: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.9/

Comment: Thanks for the dmg, I used it to download qt5.12. However, I am not exactly sure if I need to change it from directory or something because the brew info doesn't recognize it as installed. Thanks for your time again.